strace shows Segmentation fault but program exited with exit status 0
While running strace on a process, I noticed that some of the threads exited with a SIGSEGV whoever, the main process continued to execute and exited with an exit status 0. Shouldn't the process exit with an appropriate exit code? Please help in identifying what is going on here.
strace -- version 5.18
kernel -- 5.18.15-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64

--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=7, si_uid=20000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 2744190 attached
[pid 2744190] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
strace: Process 2744191 attached
strace: Process 2744192 attached
strace: Process 2744193 attached
strace: Process 2744194 attached
strace: Process 2744195 attached
strace: Process 2744196 attached
strace: Process 2744197 attached
strace: Process 2744198 attached
[pid 2744196] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fa89a131d00} ---
[pid 2744190] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xc} ---
[pid 2744195] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fa89a131b80} ---
strace: Process 2744248 attached
strace: Process 2744249 attached
strace: Process 2744250 attached
[pid 2744190] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fa89a131a80} ---
strace: Process 2744277 attached
strace: Process 2744278 attached
strace: Process 2744279 attached
[pid 2744279] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xc} ---
strace: Process 2744280 attached
[pid 2744280] +++ exited with 0 +++
strace: Process 2744281 attached
[pid 2744196] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fa89a131d00} ---
[pid 2744279] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fa89a131c00} ---
[pid 2744279] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fa89a131c00} ---
[pid 2744196] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7fa89a131d00} ---
strace: Process 2744445 attached
[pid 2744445] +++ exited with 0 +++
strace: Process 2744446 attached
[pid 2744446] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744198] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744191] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744190] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744281] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744277] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744249] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744279] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744278] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744250] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744248] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744197] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744196] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744195] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744194] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744193] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 2744192] +++ exited with 0 +++
+++ exited with 0 +++```


The obvious suggestion is those are not threads but child processes. Those are free to crash independently as much as they want.

The full strace should have something about the children starting, you can check there whether those are threads or processes.

@teapot418 These are all threads. Infact, I can see the same threads in /proc/<pid>/task with the corresponding thread_id.

Another possibility is those signals are getting handled. Hard to tell without more details about the program running.

its a java application that is trying to copy data from an hdfs cluster to a db.

typically threads are independent, as such they do whatever they need to do and exit/die without impacting the parent. show the code that starts the threads. maybes adding a callback such that the parent is notified of the child exit along with relevant information (exit status etc) may be what you are looking for ?

https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_hotspot/blob/master/src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm/os_linux_x86.cpp <- apparently the jvm has non-trivial SIGSEGV handling with some non-fatal cases like growing thread stacks
